# How does RAID compare to secure data against replication?

Tags: mysql, backup, raid, replication

I am currently trying to figure out the best setup to secure my DB data, but I also have a tight budget. My first (and obvious) solution would be to use replication. But I wonder, apart from problems and data loss occurring from physical damage to the server itself, what more benefits would replication give me, as long as we are just talking about securing storage, if  I have RAID on my server?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Advantages of replication:

- Distribution of data to another phyiscal location, not just another physical server in the same data center
- Simple loadbalancing
- Easier backups if Master server is under permanent high load (just backup the slave)
- First step to high availability solutions

Disadvantages/considerations:

- Performance: slaves machines should be similar to master as they have to do the same work (write queries)
- Master and slave may not be completely in sync - if this is a problem depends on if and how you use the slave(s)
- Bandwidth and latency to the slave(s)

(Book recommendation: High Performance MySQL, O'Reilly)

That said, you should have RAID anyway and be sure you've tested that it works (Pull out the second disk during work...).

Answer (score 4):

RAID protects you against one thing, and one thing only, disk failure. That's it. If that is all you are concerned about then that's fine.

However, by replicating your database to another server, you gain further resilience

- Protection against any hardware failure in one machine, in particular the Single Point of Failure in your RAID controller
- Protection against the server being stolen or physically destroyed
- Protection against all disks in your server failing
- The ability to perform maintenance on one server whilst still having the database accessible